# How can I map a wedge onto the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, linear-transformations, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

The wedge is given by $0< \arg(z) < \alpha \pi$, for $0 < \alpha <1$.

If I use the complex logarithm, principal branch $-\pi < 0 \le \pi$, then

$$z \mapsto w = \operatorname{Log}(z)$$
$$ = \ln|z|+ i\arg(z)$$
$$= u+iv$$

so that $0<v<\alpha\pi$, which shows that the wedge maps onto a semi-infinite, horizontal half-strip, with height ranging from $0$ to $\alpha \pi$.

What can I do next?  Is the Logarithm mapping even a good start?  I usually like it, when I see a circular region that I have to start with, but not for very great reasons other than that I know what the mapping does to a circular region...

Thanks,

Comment: Mapping a strip to the unit circle sounds like a job for a linear fractional transform, but I don't have the means to check that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment -- perhaps go to a half-plane ...and then onto the unit disk by simple symmetry arguments for LFTs.  I'll work on this now.  Thanks, @IPoiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard problem in beginning complex variable, as I learned from Ahlfors. First you apply the function $z\mapsto z^{1/a}$. It’s pretty clear that $a$ must be not too big, I guess less than $2$, and positive, I’m sure. You see that this sends your wedge to the upper half plane. Then any good map like $z\mapsto (iz+1)/(z+i)$ will get the UHP to the disk. To define $z^{1/a}$, you have to use a suitable branch of the logarithm, and that’s why you want $0<a<2$.

Comment: Wow... @Lubin.  That power map is too clever.  What if I were stuck at the horizontal half-strip, with height 0 to $\alpha \pi$?  I was stuck on this half strip after applying Log initially to the wedge.  I'm hoping to proceed from my naive approach, in case there are other clever mappings that I do not get a chance to see and memorize.  What do you think?  Is it just an overall bad idea to start with the Log mapping?  I am currently trying to go from the half-strip to a half-plane, but am not sure how...thanks,

Comment: Perhaps the $z^2$ mapping to double the angle, going from a max argument of pi/2 to pi ... so either way...we need a power mapping, I think.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't quite work...

Comment: I will stick with your suggestion.  Thanks so much @Lubin.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hi Professor Lubin -- would the principal branch of log, with $-\pi<arg(z)\le\pi$ work just fine?  There is a restriction on $ \alpha $ given in the problem statement:  0 < $ \alpha$  <1.  I don't see any issues with using the principal branch, since arg(f(z)) = arg(w) is neither 0 nor $ \pi $. (but perhaps I overlooked something...)

Comment: Yes that branch of the logarithm would be fine. I would have chosen $0\le\arg(z)<2\pi$, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, Professor Lubin -- your choice of logarithm would be more natural now that I think about it.  Have a great night, @Lubin :-)

Comment: @Lubin why $\alpha<2$. is this related to the condition that $z^{\alpha}$ is single valued if for two distinct $z_1,z_2$ we will never get $arg(z_1)-arg(z_2)=\frac{2\pi k}{\alpha}$, $k\in\Bbb{N}$. For instance wedge with opening \frac{2\pi}{\alpha}$

Comment: Well, if $\alpha>2$, then your figure isn’t a wedge at all, is it, @AlexanderCska ?

Comment: @Lubin well it is, but we have higher winding number around the origin. I am currently trying to learn the concept and it is still quite confusing.

Comment: But there is no way of defining the first-step function if $\alpha\ge2$.

Comment: @Lubin, I guess since $z^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ it will not be a single valued function.